Make Autotools project with SDL2
I am spinning up a new project. I want to use autotools for my build system, and the project will link to SDL2. However, I'm stuck writing the configure.ac file.
The documented way to link to SDL2 when it is installed on the system uses an installed command that outputs linker flags:
gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`

I find it reasonable to assume that the output of sdl2-config may change depending on the system, and that it should be run in configure, then passed to make (this may be wrong!). I'm having a dog of a time trying to set this up, though. Maybe it's because my knowledge of M4sh is very limited, but I can't figure out how to do command substitution on the target computer.
How do I properly integrate linking SDL2 and autotools into a project, and why is it done that way so I can apply those principles to future libraries I have this issue with?

Digging into the internals of automake's configure's run process, a naive command substitution written into a configure.ac's AC_CHECK_HEADER passes into the configure script unaffected. The expansion happens as the line is copied into a temporary file, and fails when that file is executed because sdl2-config outputs newlines.

I've found a method that works using pkg-config, but I don't know why it works or what I'm doing. I'll write an answer later, but I'd still love to know what I'm supposed to do and why it works.

FWIW, it's one thing to have a command substitution in a build command that you execute manually, but it's an altogether different thing to put such a command in a makefile.  IMO, your instincts are exactly right here.

I agree with @Orion's answer that using PKG_CHECK_MODULES is the way to do this. I have a few remarks to add.

As PKG_CHECK_MODULES already does AC_SUBST its variables, you do not need any extra lines which AC_SUBST the variables defined by PKG_CHECK_MODULES.

Do add a check that the PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro is actually available (m4_pattern_forbid([^PKG_CHECK_MODULES])dnl) so that if it is not, autoreconf will fail immediately with a useful error message instead of generating a broken configure script which will 100% abort with a less helpful error message but only later. This advise applies to any macro which is not part of Automake and Autoconf (AM_, AC_, AS_, m4_).

If SDL2 is actually required for your project, you do not need to deal with the conditional arguments to PKG_CHECK_MODULES at all: PKG_CHECK_MODULES will abort the configure script if SDL2 is not found and there are no conditional arguments.
The only reason to deal with the conditonal arguments to PKG_CHECK_MODULES for a SDL required project is to print additional information in case SDL is not found. You are not doing that, so you can get rid of the conditional arguments.


This simplifies the configure.ac snippet to:
m4_pattern_forbid([^PKG_CHECK_MODULES])dnl
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([SDL2], [sdl2 >= 2.0.22])

About the Makefile.am snippet:

It is a bit inconsistent to add the sdl2 cflags to all compilation units (AM_CPPFLAGS), but the library only to one program target (hello_LDADD). I would suggest explicit per compile target definitions: hello_CPPFLAGS and hello_LDADD.
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = src/main.c
hello_CPPFLAGS = @SDL2_CFLAGS@
hello_LDADD = @SDL2_LIBS@


If your project ends up using multiple libraries in addition to SDL2, the readability starts decreasing as it becomes less obvious that both the cflags and the libs are added for all libraries:
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = src/main.c
hello_CPPFLAGS = @SDL2_CFLAGS@ @LIBUSB_CFLAGS@ @ZLIB_CFLAGS@ @OPENSSL_CFLAGS@
hello_LDADD = @SDL2_LIBS@ @LIBUSB_CFLAGS@ @ZLIB_LIBS@ @OPENSSL_LIBS@

and I find grouping the library specific things together helps with that
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = src/main.c
hello_CPPFLAGS =
hello_LDADD =

hello_CPPFLAGS += @SDL2_CFLAGS@
hello_LDADD    += @SDL2_LIBS@

hello_CPPFLAGS += @LIBUSB_CFLAGS@
hello_LDADD    += @LIBUSB_CFLAGS@  # oh wait, that should have been _LIBS!

hello_CPPFLAGS += @ZLIB_CFLAGS@
hello_LDADD    += @ZLIB_LIBS@

hello_CPPFLAGS += @OPENSSL_CFLAGS@
hello_LDADD    += @OPENSSL_LIBS@




As it turns out, this is a common problem with a preexisting solution, using the external pkg-config tool. SDL2 has support within pkg-config, so I can use PKG_CHECK_MODULES to ensure the existence of SDL2 and get the preprocessor & linker flags from the configure script to the makefile.
configure.ac:
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([SDL2], [sdl2 >= 2.0.22],
        [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_SDL2], [1])],
        [AC_MSG_ERROR([SDL2 is required!])])

AC_SUBST([SDL_CFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([SDL_LIBS])

Makefile.am:
AM_CPPFLAGS = @SDL2_CFLAGS@

bin_PROGRAMS = hello

hello_SOURCES = src/main.c
hello_LDADD = @SDL2_LIBS@



I find it reasonable to assume that the output of sdl2-config may change depending on the system,

Very reasonable indeed.

and that it should be run in configure, then passed to make (this may be wrong!).

That seems most appropriate to me.

I'm having a dog of a time trying to set this up, though. Maybe it's because my knowledge of M4sh is very limited, but I can't figure out how to do command substitution on the target computer.

M4sh macros are intended for dealing with shell features that exhibit portability issues across shell implementations.  A lot of shell features are sufficiently portable that they don't have specific support in M4sh.  Where you want one of these in your configure script, you're meant to just use it directly in configure.ac.  Command substitution is such a feature.  The Autoconf manual does contain a whole chapter on portable shell programming, however, and that has a few words to say about command substitution (nothing particularly critical).
So you're looking for something like this:
configure.ac
# ...

# maybe also add a "checking" message and result, and fail if not found...
AC_PATH_PROG([SDL2_CONFIG], [sdl2-config])

# sdl2-config --cflags seems actually to output preprocessor flags, hence CPPFLAGS below:
SDL2_CPPFLAGS=$(${SDL2_CONFIG} --cflags)
SDL2_LIBS=$(${SDL2_CONFIG} --libs)

# Make those output variables:
AC_SUBST([SDL2_CPPFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([SDL2_LIBS])

# ...

Then ...
Makefile.am
bin_PROGRAMS = myprogram
myprogram_SOURCES = myprogram.c
myprogram_CPPFLAGS = $(SDL2_CPPFLAGS)
myprogram_LDADD = $(SDL2_LIBS)


As for why it's done that way, I guess it depends on what part of that you want to know about.  Some possible answers are:

Why there isn't an M4sh macro for everything: because the shell language is a perfectly good one, and Autoconf tries to leverage users' existing familiarity with it.  The M4sh macros serve to help in cases where it is difficult or tedious to write shell code that is sufficiently portable, but that is meant as an adjunct to the shell language, not a replacement.  Also, M4sh has some historical inertia.

Why should you should separate different kinds of flags: because the different kinds get used with different commands, and because their positions in those commands is sometimes important.  Or more directly, because that's what Automake expects.

Why variables are used to convey information from configure to make: because that's the Autoconf model.  Autoconf configure scripts are template processors.  They read a file containing placeholders for data, and replace those with actual data.  Autoconf uses variable names to match place holders with the data should fill them.  On the make side, variables are make's natural mechanism for data abstraction, and also a conventional way to handle the kinds of data (command names and options) that configure most often needs to convey to it.

Why AC_SUBST must be used to export variables: Autoconf is designed this way because shell scripts, including configure, can be very messy , namespace-wise.  By passing through only those data they are explicitly told to do, configure scripts reduce the cross-section for unwanted clashes.  When Autoconf is used together with Automake, this also results in slightly simpler makefiles.


I'll stop there.
